# Can navigationbar items be left-justified?

Tags: swiftui

If you use `navigationBarItems`, what you see is displayed on the right.

I want to make this on the left, is that possible?

This is a code

```
NavigationView {
  List {
  ...
  ...
  }.navigationBarTitle("New", displayMode: .inline)
  .navigationBarItems(trailing:
    HStack {
      Button(action: { self.onDismiss() }) {
        Text("Cancel")
      }
    }
  )
}
```

This is a picture

[image]

Comment: So you’re trying to put the cancel button on the left? (Clarifying the question)

Comment: @EliFront
Hi
Yes!
I tried to move cancel button to left

Comment: Use this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/3368081-navigationbaritems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you need to use **.leading**, or you can use both:

```
NavigationView {
  List {
  //...
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: { self.onDismiss() }) {
              Text("Cancel")
            }, trailing: Text("trailing"))
// ...
```

the result:
[image]